# Setting height of textbox to auto in code-behind for a dynamically created textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am creating a textbox dynamically via code, and adding it to the LayoutRoot. I want the textbox to support multiline, so I have set the `AcceptsReturn` property to `true` and `TextWrapping` property to `Wrap`. I read in another question that to set the `Height` as `Auto`, we have to use `double.NaN`, and I have done this. But, when I add it, its height is infinite, and covers up the whole space. I just want the textbox to be of a single line initially and let it increase the height when lines are added to it. Please help me with this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your `TextBox` in a `StackPanel`.  If you're doing it via code, you could do something like this, for example:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var textBox = new TextBox
    {
        AcceptsReturn = true,
        Height = Double.NaN,
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
    };

    var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);

    this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(stackPanel);
}
```

Comment: is there an alternative. This is very difficult to implement in my scenario. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative would be to create a resizable row in the grid and put the textBox in there.

```
<RowDefinition MinHeight="20"/>
```

Put your TextBox in this row:

```
Grid.SetRow(textBox,1);
```

Now if the height of textBox is Auto or, Double.NaN it should appropriately resize itself and the row.