# How to increase height when it's textwrap in textBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, word-wrap

We need handler more detail in Textbox in our windows phone Application.
when user input some string and textwrap support in textBox.
how to increase height when text content textwrap in textbox?

as fllow:

```
  <StackPanel x:Name="BuildDefaltTask_SP" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox x:Name="AddNewTaskContent_TB" Height="150" Margin="-12" FontSize="26" FontWeight="ExtraBold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `Height` to `Auto`, then it should grow with the text as you enter more lines.

You can also do this from code: like [Setting height of textbox to auto in code-behind for a dynamically created textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385026/setting-height-of-textbox-to-auto-in-code-behind-for-a-dynamically-created-textb)

Or you can control the sizing yourself using `MeasureText` - [Autoresize textbox control vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893059/autoresize-textbox-control-vertically)